# Import external script into React component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am converting a template into react components for my site. However, the template are mostly in jquery. The external javascripts are not binding well with my component and I have to bind the function with `componentDidMount()`.

```
componentDidMount(){
  $(".b-upper-title").slabText({
      // Don't slabtext the headers if the viewport is under 380px
      "viewportBreakpoint":380
  });
}
```

However, `slabText()` is not working since it is dependent on `<script src="styles/plugins/slabText/js/jquery.slabtext.min.js"></script>`. I need to import this script into the component in order to call the function. Any idea how to perform the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking a look at this library [react-async-script-loader](https://github.com/leozdgao/react-async-script-loader)